# Disable Linux hard disk support

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I'm building a custom linux kernel that should be able to access cdrom and usb mass storage devices, but not hard disks.

I tried disabling CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD, but I lose usb mass storage support.

How can I achieve that? If not possible, is there a way to remove hard disk nodes in /dev at startup?

Comment: What's the difference to a hard disk connecting via USB, or by another means, such as IDE?

Comment: I'm creating a live cd which gives you an isolated system: no network, no local disk drives (except cdrom, of course). But it should be able to access external usb pen drives, which are scsi disks (/dev/sd*). The idea is to prevent session data from reaching a network-connected machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define, what exactly "hard disk" means.

Second, you need to express the above definition as a set of `udev` rules. This way, device nodes for devices you don't want would not even get created in `/dev/` in the first place.

One nice tutorial for `udev` rules is here:

http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Relevant Q/A:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66897/what-is-the-udev-rule-to-allow-specific-thumb-drive-vendors

Comment: Changing UDEV rules is not a very comprehensive solution, as device nodes can still be created manually.

Comment: To create device nodes by hand one has to have root equivalent permissions, at which point that user can recompile the kernel and edit udev rules at will.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I'm amazed you even managed a bootable system with CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD disabled: modern Linux kernels funnel virtually all storage I/O through the SCSI layer, then treat the specific types (SATA, PATA, USB mass storage, etc.) as flavors of SCSI.

I'd try disabling things at the next layer down in the system: enable SCSI disk and CD-ROM support, then disable all methods of actually talking to those disks: low-level SCSI drivers, ATA SFF support, ACHI support, etc.

Comment: Block device layer in Linux is not equivalent to SCSI layer (the later depends on the former) - plenty of storage devices don't depend on SCSI all together (examples being various flash memory devices, like stuff supported by mtd, mmc/sd or even Sony Memstick).

Comment: @oakad, I know, but all the common ones do -- even most flash devices get presented to the system as USB mass storage, which uses the SCSI layer.  It's only direct-access flash devices that don't.